# <sessionState> configuration only works when it's cookieless

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm experiencing an odd behavior on ASP.NET [`<sessionState>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) configuration.

I'm trying to use `mode="SQLServer"`.
When I put `cookieless="true"` everything works happily as it should be and the `ASPStateTempSessions` table get filled as expected.

When `cookieless="false"` ASP.NET simply ignore my configuration and host the sessions in its process (nothing on `ASPStateTempSessions`).

I have no idea why the `cookieless` configuration is yielding such unexpected behavior.
Anyone know why this happens or how do I solve it?

By the way here's my configuration:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="MyConnectionString" />
```

---

P.S.:

I've double checked my browser cookies, it's definitely nothing to do with my browser.

I also tried to use a [custom implementation](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/cache-asp.net-session-state-provider) just to for the sake of testing.
The exact same behavior happens, only works with `cookieless="true"`.

Comment: What about value `UseCookies` instead of `false` for `cookieless`?

Comment: @Igor Same behavior.

Comment: I take it the URL then does display the correct sessionid? You could do a quick test, add some code to explicitly write/add a cookie to the `Response` object and see if it shows up in your browser. This way you will know if cookies are being blocked by your browser|web.config OR if it is something specific to `sessionState` configuration.

Comment: @Igor Cookies are being written alright (when cookieless is false). They even respect the name I've put on <forms>.

Comment: Ok, so creating your standard cookies does work. So is the sessionId also written to a cookie when its `false` and ASP.NET is not doing anything with it OR is **that** cookie not even being written. I am not sure what you mean by <forms>, do you mean the `cookieName` in the `sessionState` element?

Comment: @Igor No, I mean the actual [`<forms>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28vs.71%29.aspx) element. There's a `name` attribute that is the name of the cookie to be used. Taking it out it simply assumes the default name (`.ASPXAUTH`) and the problem persists (just checked).

Comment: Sure but <forms> is for the authentication cookie which is independent of the sessionState cookie (maybe we are agreeing here). My previous question is, is the cookie `ASP.NET_SessionId` (default name of cookie of the sessionState unless you provide an override with the `name` attribute) being written to the browser when `cookieless` is set to `false` or `UseCookies`? If not then its a matter of figuring out why the cookie is not being written, otherwise its a matter of why the cookie is not being read.

Comment: @Igor I never realized that ASP.NET used different cookies to handle authentication and session management (ty for pointing it out). No, the cookie doesn't get created (with or without `cookieName`).

Comment: After some digging it looks like the cookie will never be written, and so the DB will not be updated, until you actually set something in the Session object in one of your requests. Can you verify that by calling a request that writes something (anything really) to the Session object and then checking for the presence of that cookie? Once the cookie is there (with a guid value) then the Db should also have been updated.

Comment: @Igor It worked! I'm really not writing anything to session, writing something dummy made it work. Thank you very much! (P.S.: post as answer so I can accept it).

Comment: I am not sure what there is to solve. The session is there to hold temporary state but if you don't have anything to write to the state then that's ok too. Is there a reason you want a session id to be created for every incoming request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When cookies are used in the web.config the session will not be created on first use until something is persisted to the session object. This means that the database will not be updated and the cookie will not be written to the server. You can test if this is the case by writing some dummy value back to the Session object and then checking to see if the database record has been created and the cookie written to the browser.

Comment: I assumed that it wasn't working since I was seeing no data on the table, but in the end it was, I just didn't put anything in theuser session. When cookieless I forced to have something to be written there. Thank you for sorting out the my mistakenly assumption. (I still couldn't disable the session because I use TempData, which uses the Session).

Comment: FYI: I have this application hosted on different servers under the same hostname on the network. Sharing the session on the database and using the same machine key allow me to seamlessly load balance the servers or something alike.